# How to retrieve CheckBox SelectedValue in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my scenario I have list of CheckBoxes in the form. I have to get selected checked box values whether it is checked or not. Here I included coding part I have tried.

Html View

```
<div>
<label for="checkbox1"><b>Goverment & Professional Fees</b></label>
<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.GovermentandProfessionalFees,new { id = "govandproflcheckbox" })
<span>Payment of all fees to Government and Professional bodies are excluded.</span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#govandproflcheckbox').change(function () {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (isChecked == true)
            {
                $('#GovermentandProfessionalFees').val($(this).val());
            }
            else
            {
                $('#GovermentandProfessionalFees').val($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using this Jquery I can check whether a particular checkbox is checked or not but `model => model.GovermentandProfessionalFees` variable is still not updated that is in false state only.

Answer (score 0):

provide a value to the checkbox tag like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" value="1" />
```

In Jquery:

```
var chkValue = '';
$('#mycheckbox').click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  var chkValue = $(this).val();
}
});
```

Try this.